# Error connecting to local SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to connect to the SQL Server database, but it throws an error. Here is the code I have tried :

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=C:\\USERS\\HITESH\\DOCUMENTS\\MOVIES.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";

SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
scon.Open();
```

Error :

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Any suggestions?

Comment: check your connection string. I'm pretty sure it's incorrect.

Comment: Try using AttachDbFileName instead of Initial Catalog. More info here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: I copied the connection string and pasted. Can you suggest where is it going wrong ?

Comment: Shouldn't your Initial Catalog be the name of the database, not a full file path.

Comment: Does this database exist in SQL server and what is its name?

Comment: @PabloRomeo It throws the same error

Comment: @PraveenPaulose this is connectionstring i found : 

Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=C:\USERS\HITESH\DOCUMENTS\MOVIES.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False

Comment: I think you need to both correct the Initial Catalog, as well as escape the backslash in the DataSource.

"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFileName =C:\\USERS\\HITESH\\DOCUMENTS\\MOVIES.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correct the Initial Catalog as well as escape the backslash in Data Source:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=C:\\USERS\\HITESH\\DOCUMENTS\\MOVIES.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
scon.Open();
```